# Using Facebook “FB.Canvas.getPageInfo” inside jQuery functions

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas

I can't get Facebook Javascript functions to work inside of certain jQuery commands...

This works:

```
$("a#GetScrollTest").click( function() {
    FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(function(fbCanvasInfoObject) {
        var fbPosition = fbCanvasInfoObject.scrollTop;
        $("a#GetScrollTest").html("The scroll top value 
         is " + fbPosition + "px");
    });
    return false;
});
```

This doesn't (returns 'Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined'):

```
$("a.scrollLink").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(){
        FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(function(fbCanvasInfoObject) {
        var fbPosition = fbCanvasInfoObject.scrollTop;
        $(this).html("The scroll top value is " + fbPosition + "px");
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Anyone know why one the click method works, yet the .each() method does not?  Why does it return FB not defined?  The calls are in the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of that big script block starting with `window.fbAsyncInit` is that the Facebook SDK gets loaded *asynchronously*.

Even though you've got your calls against `FB` inside a jQuery document ready callback, that isn't sufficient to ensure the SDK is loaded when that code is executed.

Fortunately, `window.fbAsyncInit` exists for *exactly* that purpose: it won't be run until the SDK has loaded.

From [Facebook's docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/):

> The function assigned to `window.fbAsyncInit` is run as soon as the SDK
>   is loaded. Any code that you want to run after the SDK is loaded
>   should be placed within this function and after the call to FB.init.
>   For example, this is where you would test the logged in status of the
>   user or subscribe to any Facebook events in which your application is
>   interested.

Just move your `$("a.scrollLink").each(function()` into the fbAsynchInit function and all should be happy.

Comment: I can't get the jquery to operate within the fbAsynchInit function.  Is there something I need to add to switch from javascript to jquery within it?  Thanks!

Comment: I've got jQuery working within the fbAsyncInit on my pages. Nothing special was done there.